# Outlook addin forward issue

Tags: c#, outlook

I have an Outlook addin for encryption and decryption  that supports Outlook 2010 to 2013.

I am trying encrypt email to decrypt and display.

I am using open mail through mailItem_Open function

```
wrappedMailItem.Open += new MailItemInspectorOpenDelegate(mailItem_Open);
```

through this function i just decrypt email and content updated using

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = decryptString
```

Then the inspector window open and showing decrypt mail. Its working fine. I close the inspector window

mailItem_close function call

```
void mailItem_Close(Outlook.MailItem mailItem, ref bool Cancel)
    {

        try
        {
            if (mailItem == null)
                return;

            if (mailItem.Sent != false)
            {
                var signProperty = GetProperty(mailItem, "App.Decrypted");

                // NOTE: Cannot call mailItem.Close from Close event handler
                //       instead we will start a timer and call it after we
                //       return. There is a small race condition, but 250
                //       milliseconds should be enough even on slow machines.
                if ((bool)signProperty)
                {

                    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 250};
                    timer.Tick += new EventHandler((o, e) =>
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                        ((Outlook._MailItem)mailItem).Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
                        mailItem = null;

                    });

                    Cancel = true;
                    timer.Start();

                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignore random COM errors
        }

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);

    }
```

The issue is

But am not closing the inspector window (Showing decrypt message)  i just click the forward button its open new inspector window by out look and forward email and close it. Then i close the inspector window ,but the parent mailItem (Ie. inbox mail) showing in decrypt mode . In mailItem_close function i just discard all changes but its not working

This issue is not happening in Reply procedure in same steps, only happens  forward case

Please help me

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Is the Close event fired in that case?

Comment: Yes close event is fired but discard is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the message contents on the fly, you'd be better off creating your own form that shows the decrypted data without setting and potentially saving the decrypted data on the original message.